# Adding member constraint to an inlined function's paramater causes FS0752 on array accessor

Tags: generics, f#, type-constraints, arrayaccess

I've read again and again the [official Microsoft docs on type constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/generics/constraints), but I can't understand why this code doesn't compile :

```
let inline transform<'A, 'a when 'A : (member Item : int -> float)> (a: 'A) : 'a =
    a.[0]
```

> error FS0752: The operator 'expr.[idx]' has been used on an object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. Consider adding further type constraints

And with :

```
let inline transform<'A, 'a when 'A : (member f : int -> float)> (a: 'A) : 'a =
    a.f(0)
```

> error FS0072: Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed prior to this program point to constrain the type of the object. This may allow the lookup to be resolved.

Obviously I didn't understand how to use member constraint with generics in f#.
The general problem I'm facing is that I want to make generic functions over "vector-like" types like standard  `float[]`, or `Vector<float>` from `MathNet.Numerics` or even `DV` from the [DiffSharp](http://diffsharp.github.io/DiffSharp/index.html) package. 
Right now I have to get an ad hoc function for each type, like (full code) :

```
#I ".paket/load"
#load "mathnet.numerics.fsharp.fsx"
#load "diffsharp.fsx"

open DiffSharp.AD.Float64

open MathNet.Numerics
open MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra
open MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double

let l1 = 4.5
let l2 = 2.5

let a0 = [1.1; -0.9]

let inline transformVec (a:Vector<float>) =
    let x1, y1 = l1 * cos a.[0], l1 * sin a.[0]
    let x2, y2 = x1 + l2 * cos (a.[0] + a.[1]), y1 + l2 * sin (a.[0] + a.[1])
    vector [x1; y1; x2; y2]

let inline transformDV (a:DV) =
    let x1, y1 = l1 * cos a.[0], l1 * sin a.[0]
    let x2, y2 = x1 + l2 * cos (a.[0] + a.[1]), y1 + l2 * sin (a.[0] + a.[1])
    toDV [x1; y1; x2; y2]
```

As you can see this functions do exactly the same things but operates on different types.

I would like to get a generic function like (not working code) :

```
let inline transform<'A, 'a when 'A : (member Item : int -> 'a)> (toExt : 'a list -> 'A) (a: 'A) : 'A =
    let x1, y1 = l1 * cos a.[0], l1 * sin a.[0]
    let x2, y2 = x1 + l2 * cos (a.[0] + a.[1]), y1 + l2 * sin (a.[0] + a.[1])
    toExt [x1; y1; x2; y2]

let transformVec = transform vector
let transformDV = transform toDV
```

What am I missing?

---

Edit: I've got it half-working with `Mathnet.Numerics`

```
let inline transform (toExt : 'a list -> 'A) (a: 'A) : 'A = 
    let inline get i : 'a = (^A : (member get_Item: int -> 'a) a,i)
    let x1, y1 = l1 * cos (get(0)), l1 * sin (get(0))
    let x2, y2 = x1 + l2 * cos (get(0) + get(1)), y1 + l2 * sin (get(0) + get(1))
    toExt [x1; y1; x2; y2]

(transform vector) (vector a0)
```

Because it enforces `'a` (warning  `FS0064`) to be `float`, which I don't want... (`DV` from `DiffSharp` returns `D` type on `get_Item`, not `float`.)

replacing the declaration by

```
let inline transform<'a> (toExt : 'a list -> 'A) (a: 'A) : 'A =
```

makes the compiler croaks:

> error FS0001: The declared type parameter 'a' cannot be used here since the type parameter cannot be resolved at compile time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call the member `Item` like this:

```
let inline transform (a: 'A) : 'a = (^A : (member get_Item: _ -> _) a, 0)
```

However you'll get a warning,

```
~vs72B.fsx(2,5): warning FS0077: Member constraints with the name 'get_Item' are given special status by the F# compiler as certain .NET types are implicitly augmented with this member. This may result in runtime failures if you attempt to invoke the member constraint from your own code.
```

because some primitive types use "simulated members". So for a list it will work:

```
transform ["element"]
// val it : string = "element"
```

but not for arrays

```
transform [|"element"|]
System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
at <StartupCode$FSI_0009>.$FSI_0009.main@()
Stopped due to error
```

This is because the F# compiler pretends that arrays have that member, but in fact they don't.

If this is a problem, you can use a more complex solution with overloads to add special implementations for specific types, which is not straight-forward but I can show you how, or you may consider using F#+ which has an [Indexable abstraction](https://github.com/gusty/FSharpPlus/blob/5121d47416bc402bc7337e20f249cf3bfc0b20fe/src/FSharpPlus/Indexable.fs) for types which typically have an `Item` property.

Of course you can ignore that warning, with a `#nowarn "77"` but as you've seen the compiler can not check that someone will call your function with an array and fail at runtime.

**UPDATE**

Since you asked as follow up question how to use it, here's an example:

```
#r "MathNet.Numerics.dll"
#r "MathNet.Numerics.FSharp.dll"
#r "FSharpPlus.dll"

open FSharpPlus
open MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra

let x = item 1 [0..10]
let y = item 1 [|0..10|]
let z = item 1 (vector [0.;1.;2.])

// val x : int = 1
// val y : int = 1
// val z : float = 1.0
```

I'm not sure if it will work with DiffSharp and I don't know which type are you using from that library, I found `DV` multiple times.

**UPDATE2**

Regarding your follow up question for your generic `transform` function, using a simple member constraint will not be enough, you will also need to solve generically the conversion from a list to the destination type and also create a different generic multiplication which works generically but with the types you
need to deal with. You can use overloads combined with member constraint to get the desired functionality:

```
let inline item (i:int) (a: 'A) : 'a = (^A : (member get_Item: _ -> _) a, i)

type T = T with
    static member ($) (T, _:Vector<float>) = fun (x:float list) -> vector x
    static member ($) (T, _:Matrix<float>) = fun (x:float list) -> matrix [x]
    static member ($) (T, _:DV           ) = fun (x: D list  ) -> toDV (List.toArray x)

let inline toDestType (x:'t list) :'D = (T $ Unchecked.defaultof<'D>) x

type V = V with
    static member ($) (V, x:float        ) = fun (y: float) -> x * y : float
    static member ($) (V, x:D            ) = fun (y: float) -> x * y : D

let inline mult (y:float) (x:'t)  :'t = (V $ x) y

let inline transform (a:'T) :'T =
    let x1, y1 = mult l1 (cos (item 0 a)), mult l1 (sin (item 0 a))
    let x2, y2 = x1 + mult l2 (cos ((item 0 a) + (item 1 a))), y1 + mult l2 (sin ((item 0 a) + (item 1 a)))
    let g = toDestType [x1; y1; x2; y2]
    g 

let b = transform  (DV [| 1. ;  2.|])
let a = transform  (vector [1. ; 2.])
```

I still get a runtime error each time I reference DiffSharp, however intellisense shows the right types inferred.

Comment: I got it working for `Mathnet.Numerics`'s `Vector<float>` but not for `DiffSharp`'s `DV`, whose `get_Item` returns `D` type, not `float`.

Comment: But what does it returns in DiffSharp's DV when you use the ``.[]`` operator?

Comment: A `D` type value

Comment: OK, so if it returns a ``D`` when called normally, why should it returns something different when called with Static Constraints?

Comment: It doesn't, it's just that I can't produce a generic `transform` function which accounts for non float for `'a` see my edit above.

Comment: OK, that's a different problem. That's because you are constraining it with your code. You can try removing the ``'a`` type annotations, change it for a ``_`` and see if it infers it. Otherwise I can try it later, but will have to download those libraries.

Comment: exactly, that's a different problem. Could you give a short example of how the `Indexable` abstraction should be used?

Comment: I added an example, using Indexable. Regarding your code, I was unable to reproduce it, there are many issues, for instance ``l1`` is not defined. My advice is when posting code, do it as complete as possible (as I did), including #r directives, open Namespaces, all declarations. The more complete, the more chances someone will be able to help you.

Comment: Sorry for that, I added the few lines of preambles. Just install `DiffSharp` and `MathNet.Numerics` with `paket` and `generate-load-scripts` with it to get the packages scripts.

Comment: OK, I'll give another try later. Which F# version are you using?

Comment: 4.1 from up to date Vs 2017, I enforce net46 framework for MathNet, otherwise it sticks to net.core

Comment: I can't get DiffSharp to work. I get this at runtime: 'An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format'. But intellisense is pointing you where the problem is: ``let x1, y1 = l1 * cos ( ...`` in that multiplication it's telling you the type variable ``'a`` is constrained to be ``float``. This is because you're multiplying against ``l1`` (a float). So for this particular scenario you'll need a mechanism to convert float to ``D`` in a generic way, which is clearly out of the scope of your question and I don't know DiffSharp. However I'm happy to help if you point me such function.

Comment: Diffsharp use an internal "representation" of number (float for instance) which is like complex numbers but with different arithmetics, it's called Dual Numbers, and just typed with `D`. So instead of a vector, it is `DV`, which items are `D` type numbers. To convert a float like `l1` to a `D` type, it is just `D l1`. And you're right, if we convert like this `l1` and `l2`, the compiler is happy, now. But *there* is a `(*) float * D -> D` overloaded operator in the DiffSharp package, I don't understand why the type inference engine doesn't find it (bug?).

Comment: By the way what's the equivalent of `get_Item` member for slice (range) ?

Comment: See the update2, it gets really hacky because of the multiplication and the back conversion to the destination type.

Comment: Ah, it's really nice and I confirm it's working. You have a runtime error because of the native libs needed by DIffSharp in your `__SOURCE_DIRECTORY__` (they're in the `build` directory of the package). In the mean time I got a working version of the transform function with explicit parametrization of the base type conversion function (to eliminate inference errors on the `(*)` signature type), and leaving up the `Vector<'T>` type in favor of `float[]` because of too much incompatible hardcoded type constraints for the base type `'T` (alleviated by your `Unchecked.defaultof`, I guess).

Comment: Thanks, was not obvious to me that a native .dll was missing. Regarding your solution, although I don't have the code in front of me, from your description looks like the way to go. The solution I showed you is 100% generic but 100% hacky at the same time.

Comment: By the way, do you know why the inference type engine can't infer heterogeneous types infix operators like `float * D -> D` ? Is it by design ?

Comment: It can, try changing my function ``mult`` for an infix operator. It'll work for sure. The problem is in the F# definition of the generic ``*`` operator.